# androidx custom fonts on lower api's

Tags: android, xml, fonts

I am using AndroidX in my Kotlin app and I have been trying to add custom fonts. I have folder in res/font with .ttf files and 2 font families (v26 and normal). v26 file contains android: prefixes while the other file has app: prefixes.

I have also added appcompat and legacy-support implementations in gradle but somehow still I can't get the font to display properly on Android 6.0 (works on newer devices). I am setting the font family in AppTheme as:

```
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/avalon</item>
```

I have no idea what else I could try. Did anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you cannot use fontFamily for custom fonts in older APIs.

However, you can create your own TextView (extend default one) and set custom typeface:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/custom.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

}

Or to set typeface like this:

```
Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/custom.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: And is there a way to globaly set typeface with code?

Comment: From my experience, you should create custom components with custom fonts - custom editText, textView etc.
Also, you can use custom attributes to set custom font from XML, so you can specify font and read that in custom TextView and setTypeface.

Comment: I have custom styles for components with custom font but it still only works for the newer api's despite using app compat. But I'll try custom class for element now.

Comment: Which version of appCompat do you use? Try 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0' I am using androidx appcompat (since I use android x in entire app)

Comment: Try with normal app compat and see if it works. This version works for me 100%.

Comment: Also be sure that you use AppCompatActivity and android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.